# Unserialize error opencart 2.1.0.1

Tags: php, serialization, opencart

Im getting this error in the error log on opencart 2.1.0.1

```
PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 2 bytes in /home/zachovek/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_d_quickcheckout.php on line 1392
```

When the customer is placing an order via quickcheckout and at the same time is registering new profile - this error appears BUT NOT ONLY - the products in the order are not showing! This is the following line of the code:

```
$data['custom_field'] = unserialize($customer_info['custom_field']);
```

How can i fix it? 
Thank you!

Comment: You can use json_decode & json_encode instead of unserialize & serialize

Comment: I understand, but this is not custom module, its based in the theme that i use, so can you give me some example how can i change it? Thank you

Comment: You have to just use json_encode instead of serialize and jsone_decode instead of unserialize

Comment: I made it, the error has gone, but the products are still not showing in admin panel order...

Comment: You should have to save then again then it will work

Comment: What do you mean by "save"? I think now to clear the vqcache ...

Comment: actually in db we have data in serialize form, and now we used json_decode .. that's why we need to save data in db in json_encode form

Comment: This will be the hardest part for me i think... If you want you can write an answer, so i can mark it as usefull and to explain me how to do it

Comment: OK let me do it

Comment: How can i save the data in db?

Comment: Nothing speical .. just sbumit the form again fron where you have to add data from admin

Comment: Yes i did it but the products are still not showing...

Comment: You have to make sure that the data is stored in db in json_encode form instead of unserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_encode` instead of `serialize` function
and `json_decode` instead of `unserialize`